# Android Navigation Component with Nav Drawer and Action Bar Up Navigation get out of sync

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-components

I've been building a sample app with the new Navigation Architecture Component in combination with a Nav Drawer.

I have my navigation graph created, my fragments created, and the nav drawer displaying and navigating between the fragments mostly as expected. The problem is that each time I select an item from the nav drawer, it adds the fragment to the stack, instead of popping the existing one and adding the new one. This means that if I navigate to a new fragment, I've created a back stack and tapping the menu button in the action bar pops the latest fragment off the stack, instead of opening the nav drawer as I would expect. Here is my code:

```
private fun configureNavigation() {

    navDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer_layout)
    navView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.workouts_fragment, R.id.create_workout_fragment, R.id.workout_history_fragment),
            navDrawerLayout
            )

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController)

    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = navController.navigateUp()

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {

    menuItem.isChecked = true
    navDrawerLayout.closeDrawers()

    @IdRes val destination:  Int = when (menuItem.itemId) {
        R.id.workouts_nav_drawer_item -> R.id.workouts_fragment
        R.id.create_workout_nav_drawer_item -> R.id.create_workout_fragment
        R.id.workout_history_nav_drawer_item -> R.id.workout_history_fragment
        else -> {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Attempting to process an unrecognized menuItem id in the navigation drawer layout")
        }
    }

    if (destination != currentDestination) {
        currentDestination = destination

        navController.navigate(destination)
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered there were two requirements to get the nav drawer, nav graph, and action bar completely in sync with my desired behaviour.

The first is the `AppBarConfiguration`. I had to create an app bar configuration containing a set of top level destinations (the top level fragments in the nav drawer).

The second aspect was to make sure that in `onSupportNavigateUp()` function to include the app bar configuration in the call as such: `navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration).

Once I had done these two things, everything worked as expected, and the nav drawer, action bar, and up button all worked in sync without unnecessarily adding fragments to the stack.